# Comprehensive Terminology: Website, Apps

Tags: terminology

What is the accepted terminology to describe all ways a user can interact with internet-connected software (website, apps, whatever else there may be)?

web-enabled software?

Comment: You'll probably find that varies by audience.

Comment: The web isn't the Internet, it's an Internet service. The Internet predates the web by well over a decade. In fact, I'd say "Internet service" is the only comprehensive term that applies.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is looking for a specific English term and as such will better fit to http://english.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the word you're looking for is "client."

For example, if you consider Facebook to be "internet-connected software," clients would include the main website, the mobile website, the Android app, the iOS app, any third-party social media aggregators, etc.

Comment: Client/server refers to network-connected software in general, not necessarily the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Web-enabled user engagements/user experiences.